# Displaying member custom_profile_data on front end of site won't work

Tags: members

{exp:member:custom_profile_data member_id='{member_id}'}{full_name}{/exp:member:custom_profile_data}

The code above doesn't show anything. if I change the {member_id} global variable to a number it does work. Why isn't it working when the variable is in there? {member_id} displays correctly when used outside of the tag.

Comment: Also tried {exp:member:custom_profile_data member_id="{logged_in_member_id}"}{full_name}{/exp:member:custom_profile_data} with no success.

Comment: Did you try adding parse="inward"? I don't think that is it, but worth a shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{member_id}` and `{logged_in_member_id}` are [standard global variables](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/single_variables.html). All global variables are parsed **after** the modules. Take a look at the [Template Engine documentation](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/template_engine.html). The modules tags are the 15th item parsed, while the `{member_id}` is 24th and `{logged_in_member_id}` is 25th.

So, when the template engine parses the `exp:member:custom_profile`, the `member_id` isn't available yet.

By the way, you don't need to fill the `member_id` parameter because its default value is the current logged member.

Comment: Thanks! I had tried it without the member_id="" but it wasn't working originally. I had the {full_name} member custom field named {name} and it wasn't displaying for some reason. After I changed it to {full_name} I never went back and tried it without the member_id=""...anyywaaayyyss, thank you, it's working great now!

Answer (score 1):

You should see ExpressionEngine's Parse Order (http://loweblog.com/downloads/ee-parse-order.pdf). You can see that user deﬁned global variables are being parsed at last.

But if you would like to show the logged in member's profile data there is no need to pass member_id parameter.

See this statement within user doc (http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/member/#custom-profile-data-tag)

> Specifies a particular member’s information to display. By default (if
>   you do not include the member_id parameter), the tag will simply
>   display information pertaining to the currently logged-in user.